# Playlist A does not belong to account B

Tags: power-automate, azure-video-indexer

I've built a cloud flow which gets an "Action 'Get_Video_Captions' failed" error when tested.

The "Error Details" field says "Playlist 'b___A' does not belong to account '4___1'. Trace id: '9___5'." (strings replaced with underscores.)

The "How to fix" says "You should be able to fix this by verifying your account with . You may need to re-enter your password."

The connections list for the flow shows that OneDrive for Business and Video Indexer v2 are connected with no errors, so I'm not sure what it wants verified.

I've tried "verifying" my account by going to Data > Connections > Video Indexer (V2) > Edit and pasting what I assume is the right thing into the API Key field, but I'm only assuming that it wants the "Primary key" from https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/profile for this field because it doesn't seem to be documented.

Here are screenshots of the flow and the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that video already available/uploaded on the Azure Video Index service, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/upload-index-videos?tabs=with-arm-account-account? Do you see it is listed when you use a List Videos action for example?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from this screenshot. Do you have more logging from the Logic App?
Are you sure you're passing a valid video indexer videoid in the api call? Have you tried replacing the 'file identifier' with a static value that you know is correct? You can see the videoid of a video in the video indexer portal library.

Comment: In the screenshot it is clear the dynamic content File Identifier field from the when a File is created trigger action is used. This is a OneDrive for Business file id (guid)